# GWT 2.7 - Multi module setup and SDM recompilation

Tags: java, gwt

**Background:**
We use GWT for our multi-gwt-project application and we are updating to version 2.7 now.

We have a core project say gwt-shell which has the dashboard listing all the features of our application (each feature in-turn a gwt-project with multiple modules) and the shell re-directs to the appropriate sub-module depending on the event.

Since all the sub-modules/features can only be accessed through shell, we compiled the shell project (which in turn compiles all the sub-modules) and started the codeserver with the shell listed as the entrypoint.

**Problem:**
Since our project atleast has 7 gwt-projects, and we're trying compiling and launching at the parent project level, a small file change in one of the sub-modules causes SDM to recompile the entire shell which takes forever , since ours is a huge application.

Is there a way to isolate the browser to recompile only the files modified, instead of the entire project structure, or is there is a better way to handle gwt projects with our kind of setup in super dev mode?

Comment: What you describe sounds like the SDM of <=2.6. Since GWT 2.7 the SDM compiles incrementally, so only what has been changed. The first startup takes longer and compiles everything - afterwards only the changes are recompiled by reloading the page. Since there were no changes on the server side you don't have to restart the appliaction. What does your run configuration look like (arguments)?

Comment: -src java\ com.xxx.Shell -logLevel DEBUG -launcherDir <jboss-war-location>